# Retrieve wordpress username/password to register seperate account via php

Tags: php, wordpress, registration, user-accounts, password-encryption

I have an odd question about password management under wordpress.

**What I want to do:** I have a wordpress site in which users have the option to register for a separate app on the server if they chose.  Each user has their own username and password, saved using wordpress protocol; the app also requires its own username/password and can set them via SOAP.  I want to allow each user to log into the app using their wordpress username and password.

**Where I'm confused:** Retrieving the username is a simple database query so there's no issue there.  However wordpress rightfully encrypts the passwords in the database.  I'm looking for a secure way to automatically retrieve the password from the database and pass it to the app to create an account whenever the user registers for it.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You won't retrieve existing Wordpress users' passwords. These are hashed, not encrypted, and hashing is (generally) irreversible by design.

I would recommend implementing a common authorization mechanism for both the Wordpress site and your separate application, like [OAuth](http://oauth.net/). This should be better than hacking the intrinsics of WordPress password storage, because you gain much more flexibility, do not need access to Wordpress' sensitive data and do not become implementation-dependent (password storing mechanisms tend to change)

Answer (score 0):

Typically, passwords are stored in a hashed form inside MySQL databases. You will need to determine whether your secondary application stores them in the same format as WordPress. As of version 3.6, it uses an internal hashing mechansim based on a 3rd party library called "[phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)".

That said, if your secondary app either already uses phpass or could be modified to use phpass, you could simply create the requisite database records within the secondary app and copy the WordPress-generated password hash directly to it.

If the app doesn't use phpass-generated hashes, you may explore writing a WordPress plugin to "carbon copy" the other app's DB with a password hash that it is familiar with. Just be careful not to log the password in cleartext form in any way.

You will not (by normal means) be able (nor should you try, for your own protection) to reverse engineer passwords in order to re-hash or otherwise encrypt them if this secondary application uses a different password protection method.

With all of this information in mind -- I would personally explore using external authentication models / credential stores like Facebook, Google, etc -- most likely using the [OpenID](http://openid.net) authentication paradigm.